# GCP Windows Server license - buy or pay-as-you-go

Tags: google-cloud-platform, licensing, microsoft, windows-server-2022

I need to deploy a Windows Server instance into GCP. I don't fully understand how licensing work and what are options are. I find the pay-as-you-go model really expensive, the server I'll have will be up for the next 3 years and I would rather pay upfront for a Windows Server License.

Can I buy a Windows Server license outside of GCP and bring it in ?

Comment: In that case if you want (BYOL) Bring your own Windows license, you must either import an existing image, or you must build a custom image and deploy on a sole-tenant node to achieve this option, you can also review this [document-link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/creating-custom-windows-byol-images) [sole-tenancy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/sole-tenant-nodes)

If you are using windows public image to GCP, you need to proceed to 'pay-as-you-go' for licensing.